# Fail to retrieve row count for first arrow chunk error while connect the snowflake JDBC connector using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm getting the following error when my jdbc request is executed:
Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (JDBC driver internal error: Fail to retrieve row count for first arrow chunk: null.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your snowflake JDBC driver is too old and your JDK is too new, the options are in:

1. Downgrade to an earlier Java version, the minimum one you can run [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) with is [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)
2. Upgrade your [snowflake JDBC driver](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/) to the most recent version
3. Add the following line to [JMeter *system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin"  folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jdk.module.illegalAccess=permit
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

Comment: Thank you! I had to downgrade to jdk 15 https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk15-archive-downloads.html